# Нормально ли подгружать уже подгруженную библиотеку DLL? Когда стоит выгружать DLL?

Tags: c, winapi, dll

Собственно у меня 2 вопроса:

**1.Нормально ли подгружать уже подгруженную  библиотеку DLL?**

```
EXE:

...
HMODULE hm=LoadLibrary(L"DLL_1.dll");
typedef void(*func)(int);
func Func = (func)GetProcAddress(hm, "Func");
LoadLibrary(L"DLL_2.dll");
...

DLL_1:

...
    extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void Func(int);
...

DLL_2:

...
    Мне нужно использовать функцию из DLL_1. Cнова вызывать LoadLibrary()?
...
```

**2. Когда стоит выгружать DLL?**

Могу ли я использовать функции из библиотеки, после того как я вызвал `FreeLibrary()`?

**P.S.:** Причина задавания вопроса - исключение в моей программе. Рождается не сразу, после большого количества вызовов кода, где происходит описанная ситуация(в `длл` подгружается `длл` без осовождения, а также вызываются подгруженные ф-ии). Исключение в **msctf.dll** , ошибка при записи по адресу 0x00000005. Погуглил, схожие проблемы есть - все. они пишут, что исключение рождается, когда они загружают библиотеку. Вот похожий вопрос - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f74eec60-c215-42b8-b3ff-4591870d5a87/msctfdll-exception?forum=vsdebug

Comment: Превреждевременная оптимизация?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Нормально ли подгружать уже подгруженную библиотеку DLL?

Хоть это и не вызовет ошибки, но с точки зрения хорошего кода, это не очень нормально. В вашем коде должна быть одна точка инициализации библиотеки и её функций, и одна точка выгрузки её из памяти. Вы у себя должны организовать проверку, загружали ли вы эту библиотеку или нет.

> Могу ли я использовать функции из библиотеки, после того как я вызвал FreeLibrary()?

Нет, ни в коем случае. Более того, когда вы у себя делаете выгрузку библиотеки из памяти, вы должны обнулить все указатели на функции из этой библиотеки, чтобы быть уверенным, что никакая часть кода не попытается их потом использовать.

В качестве примера, как организовать инициализацию библиотеки, могу показать код, правда на Delphi - [libpng.pas](https://bitbucket.org/sas_team/sas.planet.src/src/24b54ab572311ae3a369e1f57226223c14be9ef0/Includes/LibPng/LibPng.pas?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#LibPng.pas-218). Некоторые пояснения:

- внешний код может сколько угодно раз дёргать `InitLibPng`, библиотека будет загружена только один раз, при самом первом вызове этой функции;
- выгрузка библиотеки (в `FinLibPng`) производится так же, один раз при закрытии приложения (причём, выгрузка сделана автоматическая, т.к. эта функция не доступна для вызова извне, а вызывается в секции `finalization`, но это уже особенности Delphi). В Си можно сделать подсчёт количества вызовов функции загрузки (увеличивать глобальный счётчик) и функций освобождения (уменьшать счётчик) и делать выгрузку только когда счётчик доходит до нуля.

С другой стороны, в мире ООП (Объектно-Ориентированного Программирования), одну и ту же библиотеку можно загружать/выгружать любое количество раз, главное, чтобы это происходило **симметрично**. Т.е. в конструкторе какого-то объекта мы загружаем библиотеку и инициализируем функции, а в деструкторе, выгружаем. У меня есть пример и такого использования (опять Delphi, да) - [класс-обёртка над Си-шной библиотекой](https://bitbucket.org/sas_team/sas.planet.src/src/24b54ab572311ae3a369e1f57226223c14be9ef0/Src/GeoCalc/u_DistanceCalculatorByGeodesicLib.pas?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#u_DistanceCalculatorByGeodesicLib.pas-31). Кстати, в псевдо ООП стиле, можно писать и на Си. По крайней мере, вот такие вот обёртки над библиотеками - вполне.

Answer (score 2):

Подгружать библиотеку еще раз через `LoadLibrary` - совершенно нормально. Вот что написано в [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Calling `LoadLibrary` increments the reference count. Calling the
>   `FreeLibrary` or `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` function decrements the
>   reference count. The system unloads a module when its reference count
>   reaches zero or when the process terminates (regardless of the
>   reference count).

А вот с `FreeLibrary` - хороший вопрос. Реально выгрузка не будет произведена, пока счетчик не достигнет нуля. Но считать кто сколько раз загрузил модуль - нудно. Поэтому я бы не стал так строить систему.